Efficient way to find sum of largest x elements in a subarray
I have a 1-indexed array of positive integers, and I want to make several queries to it, all in the form, 'what is the sum of the largest x integers in the subarray 1 to y inclusive?' This array is not sorted and has no particular order.
x and y are not constant and can change between queries. Note: Input to all of these is guaranteed and I don't need to check for input. Time limit is 1 second (about 100 million operations is fine) Note 2: Queries can be offline.
Right now, I'm able to solve this in O(N log N) per query or O(QNlogN)  overall just by sorting the whole array while keeping the indices, then taking the first x integers that have indices <= y. However, since I have a lot of queries, this is unfortunately too slow. (Bounds are up to 100,000 for x, y, N and Q, where N is the number of elements in the subarray and Q is the number of queries.)
Code for the too-slow priority_queue solution:
int n; scanf("%d", &n);
priority_queue<pair<int, int>> pq;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {          // scan in the array and init priority queue
    int a; scanf("%d", &a);
    pq.push({a, i});
}
 
    
for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
    int x, y; scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
    priority_queue<pair<int, int>> temp = pq;
    int c = 0, ans = 0;
    while (c < x) {
        // if the element is not in the desired subarray, remove it
        while (temp.top().second > y) temp.pop();    
        
        // element has been found
        c++;
        ans += temp.top().first*2;
        temp.pop();
    }
 
    printf("%d\n", ans);
}

Is there an efficient way to do this, possibly in O(Q) or O(Q log x) time?
Googling has turned up no answer. I've searched SO (and CS too), and have found nothing similar. Everything I have found has either been on maximum contiguous subarray sum, or maximum sum in a sorted array. I have also looked in an algorithmics book and found nothing.
Partial-sort (see here) does not work, as it is too slow (using it would be O(QNlogN) in worst-case.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

@Jan It's already mentioned that that's clearly too slow to do on every query.

Unrelated, but congratulations on your results at EGOI!

We can solve the more general problem of finding the sum of the largest x elements in any subarray (not just a prefix of the array) with a persistent segment tree. The time complexity to build the segment tree at the start is O(N log (MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE)) and the time complexity of each query is O(log(MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE)) (i.e. the log of the range of the array values). The log of the range of values will generally be quite small (at most 32 for the majority of problems), but it is also simple to reduce the log (MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE) factor to log N by applying coordinate compression.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <climits>
struct Node {
    int count;
    long long sum;
    int left, right;
};
std::vector<Node> tree{{}};
std::vector<int> roots{0};
int minVal = INT_MAX, maxVal = INT_MIN;
int update(int n, int l, int r, int val) {
    if (l == r) {
        tree.push_back({tree[n].count + 1, tree[n].sum + val});
    } else {
        int m = std::midpoint(l, r), lc = tree[n].left, rc = tree[n].right;
        if (val <= m) lc = update(lc, l, m, val);
        else rc = update(rc, m + 1, r, val);
        tree.push_back({tree[lc].count + tree[rc].count, tree[lc].sum + tree[rc].sum, lc, rc});
    }
    return tree.size() - 1;
}
long long query(int nl, int nr, int l, int r, int x) {
    if (l == r) return (long long) l * x;
    int m = std::midpoint(l, r), rightCount = tree[tree[nr].right].count - tree[tree[nl].right].count;
    if (rightCount < x) return tree[tree[nr].right].sum - tree[tree[nl].right].sum + query(tree[nl].left, tree[nr].left, l, m, x - rightCount);
    else return query(tree[nl].right, tree[nr].right, m + 1, r, x);
}
// Sum of the largest x elements in the subarray [ql, qr] (1-indexed)
long long querySumOfLargestX(int ql, int qr, int x) {
    return query(roots[ql - 1], roots[qr], minVal, maxVal, x);
}
int main() {
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<int> nums;
    nums.reserve(n);
    for (int i = 0, x; i < n; i++) {
        std::cin >> x;
        nums.push_back(x);
        minVal = std::min(minVal, x);
        maxVal = std::max(maxVal, x);
    }
    for (const int& num : nums)
        roots.push_back(update(roots.back(), minVal, maxVal, num));
    int q;
    std::cin >> q;
    for (int x, y; q--;) {
        std::cin >> x >> y;
        std::cout << querySumOfLargestX(1, y, x) << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}


Can you please describe in words how the tree works and why it is bound by the log of the range of values?

@גלעדברקן Each version of the segment tree stores the frequency and sum of the values in the array in a certain range after inserting the first i elements. Thus, the segment tree is built over the entire range of possible values. Note that coordinate compression can bring the log (range of values) factor down to log (number of distinct values in array), which is bounded by log N.

Use a running min-heap to keep the x largest integers. It should reduce the run time for each q from Y·lg(N) to Y·lg(X). It also avoids the large copy of pq in favour of a smaller of size X.
Not in addition to being untested, it_ also potentially has a lot of safety problems.
std:array<int, 100000> data;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  scanf("%d", &data[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
  int x, y;
  scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
  std::vector<int> heap { data.begin(), data.begin()+x } ; // initial heap
  std::make_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end(), std::greater<>{}); // min heap

  for (int idx = x; idx < y; idx++) { // check the rest O(Y)
    if (heap.front() < data[idx]) { // update least element
      std::pop_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end(), std::greater<>{}); // min is not at back O(lg X)
      heap.back() = data[idx]; // change back to new value
      std::push_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end(), std::greater<>{}); // keep heap consistant. O(lg X)
    }
  }

  int sum = std::accumulate(heap.begin(), heap.end(), 0) * 2;

  printf("%d\n", sum);
}

A queue where the top could be updated and sink down might be significant faster than this.

If X is constrained to a small range you could set the heap size to the maximum value of X then iterate through all the values of Y in order loading the heap. Then when you get to a particular y remove a small number of elements to satisfy that particular query, calculate the sum put the removed values back and repeat the processes.

@MartinYork Wouldn't that be Y lg Y? (ignoring the X lg Y popping)

Yes. But rather than doing Q.O(X.log(X)) doing a heap for each individual query. I am trying to amortize some of the cost of doing lots of queries and not re-doing work that has already been done, so something like doing max(Y).O(log(max(X)). Yea I know constants go away in big O, but I am trying to think of ways to measure not re-doing work and my big O is rusty

What is lg? log (common logarithm, base-10)? Natural logarithm?

@PeterMortensen lg2 2's logarithm as its a binary heap.

@PeterMortensen I'm actually surprised you have not seen lg representing base-2 log before, given your reputation. I guess we learn something new everyday huh.

Not sure it would be fast enough, but we could use Mo's algorithm for O((N + Q) * sqrt(N) * log(N)).
For the "mo segment," use x for mo_left and y for mo_right. Maintain two hashed heaps, a min heap greatest_x (with accompanying sum) and max heap others. To lower x, pop greatest_x and insert it in others. To raise x, pop others and insert it in greatest_x.
To raise y: if A[y] is greater than the smallest element in greatest_x, pop greatest_x and insert it in others, then insert A[y] in greatest_x; otherwise, insert A[y] in others.
To lower y, remove A[y] from the heap it's in.
